# Python Writerow to CSV (Output into Columns from For Loops)

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I thought I'd be able to figure this one out myself based on the last answer I received for a similar problem, but am again drawing a blank.

I'm making a Python 3 web scraper that scrapes MLB scores from The Score's website. What I want, is to output the relevant information to a CSV in the exact same layout as it shows on the website. The URL to use for this example would be:

https://www.thescore.com/mlb/events/date/2018-06-29

...and this is my current code (I know it's incorrect, but I've tried several different solutions, but none of which are giving me the output I want, trying the row.append, etc. I have the URLs list imported from a CSV currently as I want this to cycle through a list of Urls, but this is the one link to use as an example)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
from csv import reader, writer

with open('DailyResultsURLS.csv', newline='') as f_urls, open('DailyResultsOutput.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_urls = csv.reader(f_urls)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=',')
    csv_output.writerow(['Date', 'Away Team', 'Home Team', 'Away Score', 'Home Score', 'Final/Extra Innings'])


    for line in csv_urls:
        page = requests.get(line[0]).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        date = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'events__date--1OuzN'})
        teams = soup.findAll('span', {'class' : 'EventCard__title--DY0la'})
        scores = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'col-xs-2 EventCard__rightColumn--7jlDP'})
        final = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'col-xs-4 col-sm-3 EventCard__rightColumn--7jlDP'})

        for d in range(len(date)):
            csv_output.writerow([[date.text] + [teams[r1].text for r1 in range(len(teams))] + [scores[r2].text for r2 in range(len(scores))] + [final[f3].text for f3 in range(len(final))]])
```

I have also attached a picture of what my "Desired" DailyResultsOutput.csv output file should look like.

[image]

One thing to mention is that where it says "Final" on the site for each particular game, that can sometimes change to say something like "Final (13)" or however many innings that game went into, so the code can't just input the string "Final", it needs to take the value from the site.

As you'll see, currently it just makes one row with all of the needed information, but I would like it laid out under the appropriate column headers. Thanks a million for all your help again. Let me know if I've missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is one way of doing things.

**Example Code:**

```
from requests import get
from csv import reader, writer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.thescore.com/mlb/events/date/2018-06-29'

headers = ['Date', 'Away Team', 'Home Team', 'Away Score', 'Home Score', 'Final/Extra Innings']

# open writing file with context manager
with open('DailyResultsOutput.csv', 'w') as output:
    csv_writer = writer(output)
    response = get(url)

    # check if request passed
    # could do more error checking here if you wanted to
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        date = soup.find('div', attrs={'class' : 'events__date--1OuzN'}).text
        teams = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class' : 'EventCard__title--DY0la'})
        scores = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'col-xs-2 EventCard__rightColumn--7jlDP'})
        finals = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'col-xs-4 col-sm-3 EventCard__rightColumn--7jlDP'})

        # pair up teams, scores and finals
        lines = list(zip(teams, scores, finals))

        # pair up every two teams
        for away, home in zip(lines[::2], lines[1::2]):

            # extract string items
            a_team, a_score, final, h_team, h_score, _ = (x.text for x in away + home)

            # reorder and write row
            row = date, a_team, h_team, a_score, h_score, final
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

**Output:**

*DailyResultsOutput.csv*

```
Fri June 29,NY Mets,Miami,2,8,Final
Fri June 29,Houston,Tampa Bay,2,3,Final
Fri June 29,Chi White Sox,Texas,3,11,Final
Fri June 29,Colorado,LA Dodgers,3,1,Final
Fri June 29,Minnesota,Chi Cubs,6,10,Final
Fri June 29,LA Angels,Baltimore,7,1,Final
Fri June 29,Boston,NY Yankees,1,8,Final
```

**Explanation:**

- Open file for writing.
- Extract html from page with GET request using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.
- Parse html tags with [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library.
- Manipulate items and write to file using [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library.

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a better solution. Thank you for doing this. Taught me a new skill. Will close this and give feedback. Thanks again.

Comment: @MattWilson No problem, glad I could help out :)

Comment: Not sure if you'll see this, but check out my latest question here as I would love your input:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165551/scrape-finviz-page-for-specific-values-in-table